# Firebase Current User Undefined when Web Page is Refreshed

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

My scenario is simple. I created a Firebase web app and I connect using a Google account. The issue is that I need to log back in every time the page is refreshed, here are the steps :

- Initialize Firebase
- Signup with Google
- Check the current user - it is an authentified Google user
- Refresh the page
- Initialize Firebase
- Check the current user - it is undefined

The code is straightforward:

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);
...
public onAuthStateChanged(context: any, user: any) {
        if (user) { ...
...
//currentUser is defined
get currentUser(): any {
    return firebase.auth().currentUser;
}
```

Refresh the page

```
//currentUser is undefined
get currentUser(): any {
    return firebase.auth().currentUser;
}
...
if(!currentUser) {
    firebase.auth().signOut();
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
}
```

I am aware of options in the persistence of the Firebase sessions but my understanding is that this behavior is not the default. Cf. the doc:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence

I added this line to my code just in case, it makes no difference:

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
```

I also checked that the same happens with Anonymous authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you call `signInWithPopup(...)` it will show a pop up window and ask the user to sig in. For that reason you should only call this method once you detect that the user isn't signed in. The easiest way to do this, is to call it from your `onAuthStateChanged` callback:

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

...

public onAuthStateChanged(context: any, user: any) {
    if (user) { 
        console.log(user);
        ...
    }
    else {
        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I marked this at the answer but there is actually something unclear in this scenario. What triggers the onAuthStateChanged without signing in again?

Comment: The user's authenticated state is persisted, and reloaded (and verified) when you reload the page.